# Cross REST service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

So below I have one student/group service running but now I would like to get two services running, one which will hold "Groups" and one that will hold "Students" essentially splitting the service into two. But my confusion comes when I want to add a student to a group, how do you do it `cross service`?

For instance this bit of code adds a student to a group all in the one rest webservice:

```
    public void AddStudentToGroup(string group, string studentID, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        var result = Groups.Where(n => String.Equals(n.GroupName, group)).FirstOrDefault();
        var result1 = students.Where(n => String.Equals(n.StudentID, studentID)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.Groupsz.Add(new Student() { StudentID = studentID, FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName });
        }
        if (result1 != null)
        {
            result1.StudentGroup.Add(new Group() { GroupName = group });
        }

    }
```

So my question is if I split my service into two services one that holds groups and one that holds students how do I achieve what I have did in the code above (add a student to a group) but across two services? And where does the client POST to in trying to achieve this?

My entire one service looks like the code below, but I will be looking to take out groups and leaving only the student information and turning groups into its own restful web service. I just dont know how you communicate from one service to the other, while trying to achieve the above?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Linq;

namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public interface IReceiveData
    {
        #region DELETE
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/Student/{studentID}")]
        void removeStudent(string studentID);
        #endregion

        #region POST
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/Group")]
        void AddGroup(Group group);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/Student")]
        void AddStudent(Student student);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/AddStudentToGroup/{group}/{studentID}/{firstName}/{lastName}")]
        void AddStudentToGroup(string group, string studentID, string firstName, string lastName);
        #endregion

        #region GET
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "picture/{width}/{height}")]
        Stream GetImage(string width, string height);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/Student")]
        List<Student> GetStudentCollection();
        [OperationContract] 
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/Group")]
        List<Group> GetGroups();
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/GetStudentCollectionByGroup/{anything}")]
        List<Group> GetStudentCollectionByGroup(string anything);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/GetGroupCollectionByStudent/{groupName}")]
        List<Student> GetGroupCollectionByStudent(string groupName);
        #endregion 
    }
    #region Data Contacts
    [DataContract(Name="Student")]
    public class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {
            StudentGroup = new List<Group>();
        }
        [DataMember(Name = "StudentID")]
        public string StudentID { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "TimeAdded")]
        public DateTime TimeAdded;
        public string TimeAddedString
        {
            get
            {
                return this.TimeAdded.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            }
        }
        public List<Group> StudentGroup { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract(Name = "Group")]
    public class Group
    {
        public Group() 
        {
            Groupsz = new List<Student>();
        }
        [DataMember(Name = "GroupName")]
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public List<Student> Groupsz { get; set; }
    }
    #endregion 

    #region Service work
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)] 
    public class Service : IService
    {
        #region Lists
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
        List<Group> Groups = new List<Group>();
        int eCount = 0;
        #endregion 

        #region Do Work
        public void AddStudent(Student student)
        {
            student.StudentID = (++eCount).ToString();
            student.TimeAdded = DateTime.Now;
            students.Add(student);
        }
        public void UpdateStudent(Student student) 
        {
            var findStudent = students.Where(s => s.StudentID == student.StudentID).FirstOrDefault();

            if (findStudent != null)
            {
                ///findStudent values with student values --- like
                findStudent.FirstName = student.FirstName;
                findStudent.LastName = student.LastName;
            }

        }
        public void AddGroup(Group group)
        {
            Groups.Add(group);
        }
        public void removeStudent(string studentID)
        {
            students.RemoveAll(s => s.StudentID == studentID);
            Groups.ForEach(g => g.Groupsz.RemoveAll(gs => gs.StudentID == studentID));
        }

    public void AddStudentToGroup(string group, string studentID, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        var result = Groups.Where(n => String.Equals(n.GroupName, group)).FirstOrDefault();
        var result1 = students.Where(n => String.Equals(n.StudentID, studentID)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.Groupsz.Add(new Student() { StudentID = studentID, FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName });
        }
        if (result1 != null)
        {
            result1.StudentGroup.Add(new Group() { GroupName = group });
        }

    } 
        public List<Student> GetStudentCollection()
        {
            return students;
        }
        public List<Group> GetGroups()
        {
            return Groups;
        }
        public List<Student> GetGroupCollectionByStudent(string groupName)
        {
            List<Student> student = (from g in students
                                  where
                                      (from t in g.StudentGroup where t.GroupName == groupName select t).Count() > 0
                                  select g).ToList();
            return student;
        }
        public List<Group> GetStudentCollectionByGroup(string anything)
        {

            List<Group> groups = (from g in Groups
                                  where
                                      (from t in g.Groupsz where
                                              string.Equals(t.StudentID, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                           || string.Equals(t.FirstName, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                           || string.Equals(t.LastName, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                       select t).Count() > 0
                                  select g).ToList();
            return groups;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
    #endregion
```

Comment: Does the student you want to post already exist?

Comment: Yes, sorry I got confused when I first read this.

Comment: No my question is related to the logic of the application. When associating a student to a group, is a precondition that a) the student exists and b) the group exists? And lastly, what isn't working?

Comment: Ah yes both a and b exist prior to adding the student to the group. And I havent attempted it as I dont know how you even connect too and add the student to the group from two different services. I wouldnt even know where to begin.

Comment: I mean I dont even know which side the code goes on? Does it go in the groups service or the student service? Or do I create a 3rd service purely for adding students to groups? Like an intermediary sort of thing?

Comment: I don't understand. If you POST here `/AddStudentToGroup/{group}/{studentID}/{firstName}/{lastName}` that is going to call `AddStudentToGroup` with the appropriate parameters, which will update the `Student` and `Group` objects. You don't have 'two services', there's only one.

Comment: Think your missed the very first line of my question Yamen: "So below I have **one** service running but now I would like to get **two** services running"

Comment: i.e I am looking to "split" my service up, into two different services one that provides students and one that provides groups :) and my question relates to how you achieve what I have did (in one service) across two services :D

Comment: Your two questions should really be _two questions_...